# Sveltekit: Fetch user details on every page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When the user logs in I store the sessionID and user details (name, avatar, ...) in cookies. In my website's header I have something along the lines of:

```html
<script>
let user = undefined;
onMount(() => { user = getCurrentUser(); })
</script>

{#if user}
Hello {user.name}
{:else}
<a href="/login">Login</a>
{/if}
```

Unfortunately, after I login and redirect the user to the main page the main page first shows the "Login" button still (even though the cookies are present) and after a second updates and correctly shows the "Hello XYZ" element.

I think the delay comes from the `onMount(...)` which doesn't execute immediately. I think I have to read the user details on the server from the cookies and make them accessible in Svelte's `load` function. However, how do I do that for every single page given that I need to know the user state in the website's header. I could duplicate this logic for all my `+page.server.ts` scripts but that doesn't seem ideal. I am looking for something a la `+layout.server.ts` (which I know doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`+layout.server.ts` *does* exist](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-server-js), so yes, just use that.

(Data from the layout's load function is merged with the data from individual pages.)

Comment: That will include user specific data to what I'm assuming is an attempt at separating the main body of a page from said data, hence using onMount() instead of load functions. If user data is present in all pages, say on the site's nav bar for example, using load functions for user data will prevent him from leveraging cache-control public, for cloudflare etc. Afaik sveltekit doesn't provide a neat way to handle this situation.

Comment: The question was about getting access to user data in a common component outside of the page, without having to send the user data on every single page. Not sure how relevant or feasible it would be to cache the first page load, it probably depends on the application/site at hand and has its downsides (like potential layout shifts/delayed DOM updates). Most of the client side navigation will be cacheable in any case (it's mostly static JS/CSS). This optimization you mention is something I would only worry about if I have a really good reason to.